# Not able to find blob in gae blobstore

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, flash, google-app-engine

I am using wami recorder to record and store video in GAE. I am recording it and storing it and on browser console this is shown--->

```
FLASH: POST 185780 bytes of type audio/x-wav
(program):1 FLASH: Expected Samples: 95167 Actual Samples: 90112
(program):1 FLASH: Unlistening.
(program):1 FLASH: POST openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
(program):1 FLASH: POST: completeHandler
```

But whenever I am looking in blobstore viewer nothing is stored. Can someone tell me what is the problem. There is no error shown in browser console.

Comment: Please show the code that's supposed to perform the functionality. We can help you if you show what the code looks like that is supposed to work.